# Multithreaded merge sort Stack Overflow error

Tags: multithreading, sorting, recursion, merge

I'm trying to make a multithreaded merge sort and I've encountered a stack overflow error and I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
public static void concurrentMergeSort(int[] arr, int threadCount) {
    if(threadCount <= 1){
        regularMergeSort(arr);
        return;
    }
    int middle = arr.length/2;
    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, middle); //Says error here
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, middle, arr.length);
    concurrentMergeSort(left);//Says error here
    concurrentMergeSort(right);
    Thread leftSort = new Thread(new Sorting(left, threadCount));
    Thread rightSort = new Thread(new Sorting(right, threadCount));

    try{
        leftSort.join();
        rightSort.join();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    merge(arr, left, right);
}
public static void regularMergeSort(int[] arr){
    if(arr.length == 1){
        return;
    }
    int middle = arr.length/2;
    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, middle);
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, middle, arr.length);
    regularMergeSort(left);
    regularMergeSort(right);
    merge(arr, left, right);
}
```

}

I was thinking that maybe it was the thread count never decreasing, but when I modify the thread count I still get the same result. Also it was working until I added a regular merge sort and concurrent merge sort to separate it. I only added the regular merge sort as well because I was barely getting a speed increase from just having the concurrent merge sort method and the main purpose of this modification of merge sort is to increase the time it takes to sort with multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Your return condition from regularMergeSort is:

```
if(arr.length == 1)
```

When middle = 0, you will end up creating an empty array; and this terminating condition won't be hit, and there will be infinite loop. Change this condition to:

```
if(arr.length <= 1)
```

And assuming your merge function handles empty arrays, you should be good.